# CSS Code is not working in IE 6

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-6

this is the code for menu CSS code. It will work on Firefox but not in IE6.

```
.menu li a:hover .menu ul li:hover a{
   background-image:url(images/ye.jpg);
   color:#000000;
   text-decoration:none;
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

IE6 only responds to `:hover` on `a`-elements. You try to use it on a list item.

Comment: I never knew that! IE6 continues to surprise, and not in a good way!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you pasted incorrectly, it looks like you also might be missing a comma between your two rules?

```
.menu li a:hover, /* <--- comma */
.menu ul li:hover a {
  background-image:url(images/ye.jpg);
  color:#000000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made a typo, the selector looks wrong.

It should be enough with this CSS, unless you have more `ul`s inside the .menu `li`s.

```
.menu li a:hover {
  background-image:url(images/ye.jpg);
  color:#000000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial : www.learnwebdesignonline.com/css-tutorials/css-hover.htm

[Razy](http://websitedesigningcoimbatore.com)